# Is there any way to receive information about requested arguments from two clients with the function hasArg()?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am currently trying to send data (temperature and humidity from each client respectively) from two esp32 sender(clients) to another esp32 that works as a receiver, for the first sender esp32(client) i use the following code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include "DHT.h"


#define DHTTYPE DHT11

const char *ssid = "loro";
const char *password = "pingu4prez";

const int analogInPin = 0;  
int sensorValue = 0;        
int outputValue = 0;
int outputValue2 = 0; 
const int DHTPin = 22;

DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);



void setup() {

  dht.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);


  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);



  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println(" IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {


  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();

  sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  outputValue = temperature;
  outputValue2 = humidity;



  Serial.print("sensor = ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print("\t output temperature = ");
  Serial.println(outputValue);
  Serial.print("\t output humidity = ");
  Serial.println(outputValue2);
  Serial.print("temperature read test =");
  Serial.println(temperature);
  Serial.print("humidity read test =");
  Serial.println(humidity);


  char intToPrint[5];
  itoa(outputValue, intToPrint, 10); 
  char intToPrint2[5];
  itoa(outputValue2, intToPrint2, 10);



  WiFiClient client;
  const char * host = "192.168.4.1";
  const int httpPort = 80;

  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }


  String sensor1 = "/data/";
 sensor1 += "?sensor1h=";
 sensor1 += intToPrint2;
 sensor1 += "&sensor1t=";
 sensor1 += intToPrint;

  Serial.print("requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(sensor1);
   Serial.println();



  client.print(String("GET ") + sensor1 + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Closing connection");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  delay(500);
}
```

And for the second sender esp32(client) im using the following code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include "DHT.h"


#define DHTTYPE DHT11

const char *ssid = "loro";
const char *password = "pingu4prez";

const int analogInPin = 0;  
int sensorValue = 0;        
int outputValue = 0;
int outputValue2 = 0; 
const int DHTPin = 22;

DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);



void setup() {

  dht.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);


  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);



  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println(" IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {


  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();

  sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  outputValue = temperature;
  outputValue2 = humidity;



  Serial.print("sensor = ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print("\t output temperature = ");
  Serial.println(outputValue);
  Serial.print("\t output humidity = ");
  Serial.println(outputValue2);
  Serial.print("temperature read test =");
  Serial.println(temperature);
  Serial.print("humidity read test =");
  Serial.println(humidity);


  char intToPrint[5];
  itoa(outputValue, intToPrint, 10); 
  char intToPrint2[5];
  itoa(outputValue2, intToPrint2, 10);



  WiFiClient client;
  const char * host = "192.168.4.1";
  const int httpPort = 80;

  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }



String sensor2 = “/data/”;
sensor2 += “?sensor2h=”;//hum
sensor2 += intToPrint2;
sensor2 += “&sensor2t=”;//tem
sensor2 += intToPrint;

Serial.print("requesting URL: ");
Serial.println(sensor1);
Serial.println();



  client.print(String("GET ") + sensor1 + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Closing connection");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  delay(500);
}
```

As you can see, both clients have almost the same code, except for the part where the URL that is being sent is defined.

My problem is with the function *handleSentVar()* on the receiver side, which use *server.hasArg* to receive information about the requested arguments, 
as you can see in the following code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>


//U8g2 Constructor List - https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/u8g2setupcpp#introduction


const char *ssid = "loro";
const char *password = "pingu4prez";

WebServer server(80);

void handleSentVar() {
  Serial.println("handleSentVar function called...");
  if (server.hasArg("sensor1h")) { 
    Serial.println("reading from sensor received...");

                int readingInt2 = server.arg("sensor1h").toInt();
                int readingInt = server.arg("sensor1t").toInt();
                char readingToPrint[5];
                itoa(readingInt, readingToPrint, 10); //
                char readingToPrint2[5];
                itoa(readingInt2, readingToPrint2, 10); 

                Serial.print("Lectura de temperatura recibida: ");
                Serial.println(readingToPrint);
                Serial.print("Lectura de humedad recibida: ");
                Serial.println(readingToPrint2);
                Serial.println();
                server.send(200, "text/html", "Datos recibidos");
          }
   }

}

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Configurando AP...");



  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("Dirección IP del AP: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.on("/data/", HTTP_GET, handleSentVar); // when the server receives a request with /data/ in the string then run the handleSentVar function
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("servidor HTTP iniciado");

}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

How can I make the function *handleSentVar()* receive information from both clients?

Comment: add an argument to identify the client

Answer (score 0):

On the receiving client you use two lines with server1 which has not been defined in the posted program

```
Serial.println(sensor1);
...
client.print(String("GET ") + sensor1 + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +                "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

so the code of server1 should only contain server1 and for reading server2h and on the other server2 and for reading server1h.
To make maintenance simpler the program should be equal on all units, except a clientId :

```
uint8_t clientId = 1 // (range 1 -255) and 0 we should not use
....
String sensor = “/data/”;
sensor += “?clientID=”;
sensor += clientID;
sensor += “&sensorh=”;//hum
sensor += intToPrint2;
sensor += “&sensort=”;//tem
sensor += intToPrint;
....
client.print(String("GET ") + sensor + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +                "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

To ensure longlasting performance gat rid of the String class, because the heavy use will fragment heap like swiss cheese and cause unpredictibale reboots.
As an example starter how to:

```
char clientId ="12"  // saves the conversion

char sensor[256] =  {'\0'}; /* Defined globally - Used for sensor data
char message[512] =  {'\0'}; /* Defined globally - Used for message to send
....
strcpy (sensor, “/data/”);               //Start at the beginning of the array (empties it)
strcat (sensor, “?clientID=”);           // Append to the array content
strcat (sensor, clientID);
strcat (sensor, “&sensorh=”);//hum
strcat (sensor, intToPrint2);
strcat (sensor, “&sensort=”);//tem
strcat (sensor, intToPrint);
....
client.print(message);
```

The message will be built the same way. 
The fixed length arrays are placed in stack and we are using this containers to compose the data needed dynamicly.
Strings (with capital S) on avr micro controllers are a source of evil ;-)